# nav menu not centering properly using 960 grid

Tags: centering, 960.gs, nav

im trying to create a basic profile for someone and am practicing using the 960 grid system.

I've since got the hang of using grids enough to position most elements, however the menu seems a little off to me, the right side seems to be bigger then the left, even though ive centered the menu itself and its at 100% width.

Does anybody have any ideas on why it is playing up?

Site url is http://digitalgenesis.com.au/sites/alice
css is http://digitalgenesis.com.au/sites/alice/css/main.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce the ".nav a:hover"-s padding. I think this is the problem.

Comment: i have decreased the padding and problem with menu is still there? any other ideas why it may be displaying like that, i think it may have something to do with the 960.gs

Answer (score 0):

Try the CSS like this:

```
.nav{margin-top: 20px;background:black; color:white;  padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;text-align:center; }

.nav li{display:inline; }
.nav a:hover{background:white; color:black; padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;}
.nav a{text-decoration:none; color:white; }
.footer{background:black; color:white; margin-top:20px; position:fixed; width:100%; bottom:0px;}

#top{width:100%; background:black; color:white;}

.title{font-size:26px; margin-top:45px; padding-left :10px;}

.wrapper{margin-top:50px;}

.logo{margin-left:0px;}
```